# $P$ is at constant distance $2$ from point $(3,5)$. Find the equation of the locus of $P$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

The question states:

> P is at a constant distance of two units from the point (3,5). Find the cartesian equation of the locus of the set of points P in each case.

To solve this I drew it out, but I do not know what they mean by a 'constant distance of two units'. So at first I made it with the coordinates (5,y) as i added 2 to the point (3,5), but it didn't work so now i don't know what to do.

Please help.

Comment: The locus is a *circle*: the circle with centre $(3,5)$ and radius $2$.

Comment: It's the set of all points with distance 2 from $(3,5)$: does it sound familiar?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a circle of centre $C(3,5)$ and radius $r=2$, so the equation becones:
$$(x-3)^2+(y-5)^2=4$$